# Qual a diferença entre Template e Layout?

Tags: aplicação-web, layout, template, webdesign

Gostaria de saber a diferença semântica, visual e no desenvolvimento web front-end e back-end.

@edit

**Relacionadas:**

- Existe algum tipo de dependência? Para ter o layout é necessário ter
  o template?

Comment: Acho que a pergunta está completamente dentro do escopo do site

Comment: Trabalho com desenvolvimento web já faz algum tempo, seria difícil dar uma definição que não fosse baseado em opinião então só me arrisco a dizer o seguinte: Acho que são sinônimos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Os conceitos para Template e Layout se aplicam além da web, e são utilizados por N áreas. Focando ao desenvolvimento web como sua dúvida:

Template

> É um conjunto de arquivos e instruções, contendo apenas a parte visual da  apresentação do conteúdo. É um modelo de documentos que dará forma ao conceito final.

Layout

> É a forma como o conteúdo é formatado e apresentado, a estrutura e diagramação.

Fazendo uma analogia barata: Imagine que vamos construir uma pipa(espero que já tenha feito isso), a estrutura básica de uma pipa é a mesma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso, é o template.

Porém a cor da seda, o tamanho da rabiola ou os desenhos dela podem ser alteradas sem influenciar na estrutura principal dela e são apenas para enfeite. Aqui temos o layout.

@edit

> Existe algum tipo de dependência? Para ter o layout é necessário ter o template?

Um template terá um layout, a forma como os dados são organizados para exibição - mas um layout não precisa estar em um template, você pode criar um documento único e que não precise de template ( um modelo padrão a seguir ).

Fontes:

Layouts

- Definição: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/layout
- Layout de um slide - https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/O-que-%C3%A9-um-  layout-de-slide-3a67bbc6-f433-4890-8549-398c3b0bf934
- Estudo do layout - http://www.producao.ufrgs.br/arquivos/disciplinas/393_seq_3_tipos_layout.pdf
  Sobre layout - http://www.uff.br/sta/textos/ar022.pdf
- Layout de empresas e seus benefícios - http://www.abepro.org.br/biblioteca/enegep2013_TN_STO_177_010_23292.pdf

Templates

- Definição: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/template
- Modelos de documentos - http://www.governoeletronico.gov.br/sisp-conteudo/nucleo-de-contratacoes-de-ti/modelo-de-contratacoes-normativos-e-documentos-de-referencia/templates-modelos-de-documentos
- Template em C++ - http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~hleitao/EI/Templates.pdf

Comment: Basicamente o que eu pensava, pode citar fontes (mesmo que não se referindo ao desenvolvimento web)?

Comment: Existe algum tipo de dependência? Para ter o layout é necessário ter o template?

Comment: @KaduAmaral adicionei algumas fontes.

Comment: @RowAraujo editei a resposta e adicionei sua pergunta em quote, respondendo-a.

Answer (score 0):

**Layout** é a forma com que um conteúdo é apresentado, formatado e diagramado. É mais ligado à sua *estrutura* de apresentação. (O que?)
Normalmente não é o arquivo final da sua ideia, mas pode ser parte integrante dele.

**Template** é o conjunto de arquivos e orientações para a disposição do conteúdo e da *apresentação visual*. (De que forma?) Este conjunto de arquivos dá a forma ao conceito ou o *tema* do projeto, da ideia, do site/app.

Existe uma dependência entre eles, pois um template já foi um layout. Pode-se ter um template com um layout específico, e em cima do mesmo template se trocar o layout. É possível também ter um template único que possui vários layouts.

Quando penso nesta temática, lembro do *Powerpoint*. Você abre o programa, e ele te dá algumas opções de slides (slide branco, título, subtitulo, imagem, conteudo, coluna). É um modelo simples, e você utiliza aquilo que faz sentido à sua apresentação. Você pode utilizar esta ideia e pode alterar. *(layout)*

Ou você pode pegar um modelo pronto, que já vem com animações aplicadas, com desenhos diferenciados, caixas de texto localizadas em locais determinados e até diferenciados, tudo isto com o objetivo de formar um conceito visual. Para chegar a este arquivo fechado, alguém pegou um layout e o modificou até que este fosse coerente com o tema que se pretende.*(template)*

Ou um *exemplo* ainda mais simples. Desenhe uma pessoa. Um boneco de palito é um layout. Tem cabeça, tronco e membros, na ordem necessária, nos locais certos, e na quantidade suficiente para sua identificação. Agora se você vai fazer seu desenho com tinta, com lápis, com uma certa espessura de traço, realístico, colorir, com determinado estilo, etc; isto seria o template.